# LLVM generates unefficient IR

Tags: c++, optimization, llvm

I playing with LLVM and tried to compile simple C++ code using it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int test = rand();
  if (test % 2)
    test += 522;
  else
    test *= 333;
  printf("test %d\n", test);
}
```

Especially to test how LLVM treats code branches
Result I got is very strange, it gives valid result on execution, but looks unefficient

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %1 = tail call i32 @rand() #3
  %2 = and i32 %1, 1
  %3 = icmp eq i32 %2, 0
  %4 = add nsw i32 %1, 522
  %5 = mul nsw i32 %1, 333
  %6 = select i1 %3, i32 %5, i32 %4
  %7 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([9 x i8], [9 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 %6)
  ret i32 0
}
```

It looks like it executing both ways even if only one is needen
My question is: Should not LLVM in this case generate labels and why?
Thank you

P.S. I'm using http://ellcc.org/demo/index.cgi for this test

Comment: c or c++?  please decide.

Comment: It's doesn't really matter in this case, basically question about llvm

Comment: It matters because of the tags, you speak about c++ but you tagged c

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry then, I changed it to C++

Comment: LLVM IR isn't executed anyway, it's IR

Comment: I understand, but if enable translation to X86 it still will produce similar code
main:
 subl $12, %esp
 calll rand
 movl %eax, %edx
 imull $333, %eax, %ecx
 addl $522, %edx
 testb $1, %al
 cmovel %ecx, %edx
 subl $8, %esp
 pushl %edx
 pushl $.L.str
 calll printf
 addl $16, %esp
 xorl %eax, %eax
 addl $12, %esp
 retl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Branches can be expensive, so generating code without branches at the cost of one unnecessary `add` or `mul` instruction, will usually work out to be faster in practice.

If you make the branches of your `if` longer, you'll see that it'll eventually become a proper branch instead of a `select`.

The compiler tends to have a good understanding of which option is faster in which case, so I'd trust it unless you have specific benchmarks that show the version with `select` to be slower than a version that branches.

Comment: So, it's because of optimization pass, got it, thank you

Comment: @EgorZyx Yes, when compiled without optimizations, there'll be a branch. The optimizer replaces the branch with a `select`.